# How to build this into APK?

Tags: java, linux, gradle, manjaro

I wanted to build this app
[Link to the code](https://github.com/asifrpatel/ImageEraser)

Can anyone guide me on how to build this into an APK.

I am new on the gradle builder.

I installed it on my system just to build this app.

I use Manjaro Linux.

Thanks in advance

I tried

`gradle build`

It said

```
Welcome to Gradle 8.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Kotlin DSL: new reference documentation, assignment syntax by default
 - Kotlin DSL is now the default with Gradle init
 - Improved suggestions to resolve errors in console output

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/manveer/Desktop/ImageEraser/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s
```